# ARCore SceneForm HDR Room image

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, hdr

By default Arcore/Sceneform uses a room as HDR environment image. How do I replace it?

[Default HDR Room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o4NJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to set own environment map. Track this feature request if you want to follow the development:
[Support for user provided IBL?](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/451)